# How to register Dot net framework 4.6.2 on IIS 8.5 in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: iis, aspnet-regiis.exe, .net-4.6.2

I installed dot net framework 4.6.2 from [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48137) path & now want to register this in IIS.

If it was a earlier framework version (2.0,3.5,etc ) & an earlier server ( For Eg Windows 2003), I would have typed the following command
in the appropriate path.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i
```

However, I cannot find the folder path of 4.6.2 on this server. & even installing this command from here gives the below message :

> Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0  Administration
>   utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine. 
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.  Start
>   installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).  This option is not supported on
>   this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead
>   install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows
>   Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the
>   dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.  Finished installing 
>   ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).

I know the web link in message is for 4.5 because 4.5 is an in-place upgrade for 4.0.

My website gives this error :

> The 'targetFramework' attribute in the  element of the
>   Web.config file is used only to target version 4.0 and later of the
>   .NET Framework (for example, '').
>   The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is
>   later than the installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a
>   valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required
>   version of the .NET Framework.

The relevant part of web.config is :

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Maybe this procedure will also work for version 4.6.2 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2736284/how-to-install-asp.net-4.5-on-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012

Comment: I could see 4.5 but not 4.6 through it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out I had downloaded a wrong installer. it was of 4.6 whereas I needed 4.6.2 which is available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53344).

The question deserves deletion but i wont coz some one else might commit the same sin.

Comment: Now i know why answering on Stack overflow matters. faced the same issue after 1.5 years for another version.

Answer (score 5):

For applications with target framework 4.6, register with these paths (depends on x64 or x86 version of Windows):

> X86: %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
>
> X64: %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

In command prompt, first got to one of above directory 
then run

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

In Application Pool setting use .Net Framework v4.0.30319

Comment: 4.5 will work but 4.6.2 does not work this way. btw what was your os version ? This might help others.

Comment: I am talking about operation system. windows server version ?

Comment: ohh sorry. Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 2):

IIS will not display the .NET 4.6.2 application pool when you select the .NET CLR version for application pool. Both 4.0 and 4.6.2 will use .NET CLR Version v4.0.30319.

Here is the link for reference:

https://forums.iis.net/t/1237493.aspx?Link+net+framework+4+6+2+windows+2012R2+to+IIS